# ¿Por qué pasa esto? Bucle for en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Al introducir este código en Python:

```
for i in (0,7):
    print('i is '+str(i))
    i=i+1
```

Obtengo esto:

```
i is 0
i is 7
```

¿Por qué sucede? Me gustaría que aparecieran todos los números del 0 al 7. Es decir, i is 0, i is 1, i is 2, y así sucesivamente hasta el 7.

Comment: (0, 7) es una tupla. Tiene dos elementos: 0 y 7. Estas pensando en `range(0,7)`.

Comment: Para formar una cadena, es mejor usar f-string: `print(f"i es {i}")` Mucho más simple y directo. Googlea "f-string python"

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Para que te de el resultado que quieres, debes incluir la clase `range` delante del paréntesis para indicar el rango del bucle. Además, si quieres que se incluya hasta el 7, debes indicar entre paréntesis `(0, 8)` ya que Python no incluye en el bucle el último número indicado, es decir, entiende que el rango es desde del 0 hasta el 7 (sin incluir el 8). El código quedaría así:

```
for i in range(0,8):
    print('i is '+str(i))
    i=i+1
```

Output:

> ```
> i is 0
> i is 1
> i is 2
> i is 3
> i is 4
> i is 5
> i is 6
> i is 7
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(0,7):
    print('i is '+str(i))
```

Para recorrerlo, necesitas usar la palabra "range" en el ciclo for, con esa palabra, entre los parametros le das un inicio y un fin y le decís que recorra dentro de ese rango imprimiendo como vos gustás.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [answer]. El código correcto mostrando qué debía haber escrito **no responde a la pregunta:** ¿Por qué sucede? Cuando quieras aportar, ten presente que lo ideal es **responder a la inquietud** y explicar lo ofrecido para que las personas puedan aprender. La mera exhibición del conocimiento sólo es útil para el **ego**

Comment: Además lo que pusiste te imprimiría hasta el 6, no hasta el 7.